# Получить и текст из input и добавить его в ссылку

Tags: javascript

Вот код, который генерирует ссылку из input при нажатии на кнопку. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии не генерировал, а сразу переходил по ссылке?

```
<form name="idform">
<input type="text" name="id" value="Введите id">
<input type="button" value="ок!" onclick="document.getElementById('x').innerHTML='<a href=http://ya.ru/?id='+escape(document.forms['idform'].elements['id'].value)+'>Ссылка</a>'">
</form>
<p id="x"></p>
```

Comment: почему вместо инпута просто не использовать тег А?

Comment: Можно и <a> в принципе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form name="idform">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="Введите id">
    <input type="button" value="ок!" onclick="location.href='http://ya.ru/?id='+escape(document.forms['idform'].elements['id'].value)">
</form>
```

Comment: Всё, получилось!

Comment: можете заменить `value="Введите id"` на `placeholder="Введите id" ` подробнее http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/placeholder

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант с другим подходом:

```
<form name="idform">
    <input type="text" name="id" 
    placeholder="Введите id"
    onchange="document.getElementById('link').href='http://ya.ru/?id='+escape(this.value)" />
    <a id="link" href="http://ya.ru/">ок!</a>
</form>
```